# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I have created the news blog in SharePoint 2013. Attached the default image from custom SharePoint list . by accessing with the machine name the images are shown properly.but while accessing with the machine IP address the image requires the permission to show.

suggest an idea to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Points to check:-**

1. Check whether the server IP is static or dynamic. It should be dynamic.
2. Try creating "Alternate access mapping" in central admin with Default and Intranet zones. In default you can specify the IP address and in intranet zone you can specify the machine name.
3. Try to remediate the issue by creating a HOST FILE entry in the client machine against IP i.e.IP Address   m/c name.